# How to Enable all state list for State and country picklist

Tags: picklist, dependent-picklist, country-and-state

We were using the state and country text field in address. Now,  we have enabled the standard state and country picklist. But the state picklist is shown for only 9 countries. Eg. USA has state picklist but united kingdom does not have it. 
I want state picklist for the rest of the countries. One option is to add the state for each country manually.
Is there any other option to save the states for the rest of the countries?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it manually. You're  touching on the question "what is a State?" One country might recognize something as a State where another one doesn't (it could recognize it as a Territory). Also, certain countries are not universally recognized.

If you want to see what I mean, check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_with_limited_recognition#Present_geopolitical_entities_by_level_of_recognition